# How to Enable UART Interrupt For PIC32MX?

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt, pic, pic32

I was trying to create a UART driver for the PIC32MX320F128H, when I noticed that any time the UART IRQ occured, it would crash the system.

The Debugger told me that the program was halting at these lines(119 - 21)? of ctr0.s every time.

```
\_reset:
jal \_startup

        nop
```

Here is the BOARD setup

```c
// BOARD Setup
\#pragma config POSCMOD      = XT        // Set oscillator to XT, crystal mode.
\#pragma config FPBDIV       = DIV_2     // Set peripheral clock to run at half sys clock
\#pragma config FWDTEN       = OFF       // Disable watchdog timer
\#pragma config CP           = OFF       // Disable Code protect, ensures all memory is available
\#pragma config FPLLMUL         = MUL_20    // PLL Multiplier
\#pragma config FPLLODIV     = DIV_1     // System PLL Output Clock Divide

\#define SYSTEM_CLOCK 80000000L
\#define  PB_CLOCK SYSTEM_CLOCK/2

\#define TRUE 1
\#define FALSE 0

// UART DEFINES
\#define UART_IBITS 0x1C000000   // ERR, RX, TX interrupt bits
\#define ERR_IBITS 0x4000000
\#define RX_IBITS   0x8000000
\#define TX_IBITS 0x10000000

\#define STA_OERR_BIT 2          // U1STA bit assosciated with OERR

\#define TEST_CHAR 0x41          // char to send and test stuff, A in ascii

\#define U1_PRIORITY 0b110       // don't know what this should be

\#define U1_SUBPRIORITY 0b01     // don't know what this should be either
```

Here is the UART setup

```c
void Uart_Init(unsigned long baudRate) {
AD1PCFG = 0xffff;               // Set PORTs to digital mode

// Disable interrupts to avoid crazy malloc errors while initing CBuffs
__builtin_disable_interrupts();

// Initialize CBuffers
RXBuff = InitCBuff();
TXBuff = InitCBuff();

// Enable interrupts after cbuffs are initialized
__builtin_enable_interrupts();

// Disable stdout to UART2
setbuf(stdout, NULL);

// Clear control registers
U1MODECLR = 1;
U1STACLR = 1;

// Clear RX, TX registers
U1RXREG = 0;
U1TXREG = 0;

// Set Baudrate, U1BRG should be 20 or 21. In this case it is 21.
U1MODEbits.BRGH = 0;    // enable high baudrate mode
U1BRG = (PB_CLOCK / (16 * baudRate)) - 1;

// Turn on the UART
// Note, that by default the UART is configured for 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, and no parity.
U1MODEbits.ON = 1;    // 8 bit 1 stop bit

// Enable RX and TX pins
U1STAbits.URXEN = 1;
U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1;

// Enable interrupts RX and ERR interrupts. TX will enable when TXBuff has chars
IEC0bits.U1RXIE = 1;
IEC0bits.U1EIE = 1;
IEC0bits.U1TXIE = 0;

// Set Interrupt priority and subpriority
IPC6bits.U1IP = U1_PRIORITY;
IPC6bits.U1IS = U1_SUBPRIORITY;

// Set interrupt modes
U1STAbits.URXISEL = 0b00;   // flag when char received
U1STAbits.UTXISEL = 0b10;   // flag when buffer is empty


}
```

Finally, here is the ISR definition

```
void __ISR(_UART1_VECTOR, IPL4AUTO) IntUart1Handler(void) {
```

I also tried to use a deprecated method to enable the interrupts, but I couldn't even figure out how to get the plib library working so that didn't get far.

```
// Depreceated method.
void __attribute__ ((nomips16)) INTEnableSystemMultiVectoredInt(void)
{
    unsigned int val;

    // set the CP0 cause IV bit high
    asm volatile("mfc0   %0,$13" : "=r"(val));
    val |= 0x00800000;
    asm volatile("mtc0   %0,$13" : "+r"(val));
    
    INTCONSET = _INTCON_MVEC_MASK;

    // set the CP0 status IE bit high to turn on interrupts
    INTEnableInterrupts();
}
```

I was really at the end of my wits until [Rich TBCO](https://forum.microchip.com/s/user-profile?&userId=0053l00000KOOiMAAX&page=1&offset=0&selectedTab=discussionTopics) from the MPLAB forums pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You took the [tour], which is good, but unfortunately rare. Thank you! You might want to reduce your program to a [mre] and to indent it properly to help us help you. Please add also the commands to build. Did you check that the stack pointer is set up? Did you check that the interrupt vector is set up?

Comment: First thing to do is inspect the interrupt vector table and ensure that it is valid.

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks, I went ahead and consolidated my question to make it more relevant.

Comment: @Clifford The vector was valid, it was provided by a MPLAB library. It turns out I wasn't enabling interrupts correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't enabling interrupts correctly. Here is how I enabled the UART interrupts following [this guide](https://microchipdeveloper.com/xwiki/bin/view/products/mcu-mpu/32bit-mcu/PIC32/mx-arch-cpu-overview/exception-mechanism/usage/).

There's really just seven steps for this. Steps 3 through 7 should be done in order in your program.

1. include xc.h and sys/attribs.h
2. Create the ISR. Make sure the priority parameter here matches the priority specified in the interrupt configuration.
3. Turn off the peripheral.
4. Configure the Interrupt, in this order: Set the priority, set the sub priority, clear the flags, and then enable the interrupts
5. Enable multi-vector interrupts.
6. Enable global interrupts
7. Enable the peripheral

Here is how I configured the UART following these steps.

```
    #include <xc.h>
    #include <sys/attribs.h>
    void Uart_Init(unsigned long baudRate) {
    // Set Ports to digital mode, configure later to only do UART pins.
    AD1PCFG = 0xffff;

    // Initialize CBuffers
    RXBuff = InitCBuff();
    TXBuff = InitCBuff();

    // Clear control registers
    U1MODECLR = 0xFF;
    U1STACLR = 0xFF;

    // Clear RX, TX registers
    U1RXREG = 0;
    U1TXREG = 0;

    // Set Baudrate, U1BRG should be 20 or 21. In this case it is 21.
    U1MODEbits.BRGH = 0; // enable high baudrate mode
    U1BRG = (PB_CLOCK / (16 * baudRate)) ;

    // Turn off the UART
    U1MODEbits.ON = 0;

    // Enable RX and TX pins
    U1STAbits.URXEN = 1;
    U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1;

    // Set interrupt modes
    U1STAbits.URXISEL = 0b00; // flag when char received
    U1STAbits.UTXISEL = 0b10; // flag when buffer is empty

    // Set Interrupt priority and sub-priority
    IPC6bits.U1IP = 4;
    IPC6bits.U1IS = 1;

    // Clear flags
    IFS0bits.U1EIF = 0;
    IFS0bits.U1RXIF = 0;
    IFS0bits.U1TXIF = 0;

    // Enable interrupts RX and ERR interrupts. TX not necessary for this simple program
    IEC0bits.U1RXIE = 1;
    IEC0bits.U1EIE = 1;
    IEC0bits.U1TXIE = 0;
    
    // Enable multi-vector interrupts
    INTCONSET = _INTCON_MVEC_MASK;
    
    // Enable Global Interrupts
    __builtin_enable_interrupts();
    
    // Enable UART
    // Note, that by default the UART is configured for 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, and no parity.
    U1MODEbits.ON = 1;
}
```